# Geting Profile Details from LinkedIn using JavaScript API

Tags: php, javascript, html, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get details of a user from his/her LinkedIn profile using JavaScript API. but the problem is i only getting the details such as firstName, lastName, headline and profile picture. other than that i'm not able to get anything.
I have followed the tutorial in [Linkedin Developer](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_profile/) and i want to add fields like **industry**, **network**, **date-of-birth**, **main-address**,

Comment: The link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

They are right here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

But the point is accessing those fields for another account (not yours or your API key) might be not possible due to policies.

Update for comment:

I assume you are following the guide in the link you provided first and you are already getting the results you want (name, picture etc...). For the other fileds just provide the field name in the link I pasted above and see what happens. for example change the field line to:

```
IN.API.Profile("me")  .fields(["industry", "network", "date-of-birth"])
```

That is use the field names in that link and do wathever you want with the returned data.

Comment: No, i'm not getting details from another persons account i just want to get details from my LinkedIn account??

Comment: Check my update, it is just replacing the name of the fields you want in the example code.

Comment: i have doing the same way you have suggested but the thing is it gives out put to thr fields like "education", "skills" as [object Object], can you explain me why is that?

Comment: Things like `educations` are a separate object themselves so you have to do another special query to access theire fields.

Comment: No secondary queries needed to get educations, just ask for them in the same query, and parse out the returned JSON data as needed. Asking: `educations:(id,school-name)`; parsing, where result is set to the LinkedIn JSON response: `for(education in result.educations) { var id = education.id; var name = education.schoolName; }`

Comment: Dear Paul i have tried the way you have mentioned, but the out put is come as "undefined" for the fiels in education such as "id:, "schoolName" etc...

Comment: I have manage to over come the problem, thnx to everyone for helping me!!

Comment: Can you post the working code? I don't understand how to get the result object if my call is:

Comment: IN.API.Profile("me").result(displayProfiles);